# Oauth2 in Python with Flask gets 302 from API

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to access MeisterTask's API with Python and Flask, and no matter what I do, I seem to always get a 302 code in return from the API, although I can get an access token (or so I think). Here is the code I have so far (I tried reducing it, this is the smallest snippet I could get that replicates the error):

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request, jsonify
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = "development"
oauth = OAuth(app)

meistertask = oauth.remote_app(
    'meistertask',
    consumer_key= "XXXXXX",
    consumer_secret= "XXXXXX",
    request_token_params={"scope" : "meistertask"},
    base_url='https://www.meistertask.com/api',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='GET',
    access_token_url='https://www.mindmeister.com/login/oauth2/token',
    authorize_url='https://www.mindmeister.com/oauth2/authorize'
    )

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'meistertask_token' in session:
        me = meistertask.get('user')
        return jsonify(me.data)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return meistertask.authorize(callback=url_for('authorized', _external=True))


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('meistertask_token', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/login/authorized')
def authorized():
    resp = meistertask.authorized_response()
    print(resp.get('code'))
    if resp is None or resp.get('code') is None:
        return 'Access denied: reason=%s error=%s resp=%s' % (
            request.args['error'],
            request.args['error_description'],
            resp
               )
    session['meistertask_token'] = (resp['code'], '')
    return "Hello"


@meistertask.tokengetter
def get_meistertask_oauth_token():
    return session.get('meistertask_token')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And here is the traceback:

```
flask_oauthlib.client.OAuthException: Invalid response from meistertask 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__ return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e) 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise raise value 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise raise value 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) 
File "~\Documents\MeisterTaskServer\hello.py", line 49, in authorized resp = meistertask.authorized_response() 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask_oauthlib\client.py", line 707, in authorized_response data = self.handle_oauth2_response(args) 
File "~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask_oauthlib\client.py", line 692, in handle_oauth2_response
```

### Things I have tried

- Tried to modify the method to get the access token from GET to POST. The API clearly states that I should use GET, yet every other example I have seen on flask_oauthlib's GitHub uses POST (the examples are 3 years old, but some still work, namely the GitHub one). Either give the same result.
- Tried doing it barebones, without any library. The resulting code was thrice as long and also had more problems.
- Used Django instead of Flask. Never even managed to get the hello world example going, it was too much work, and also I have discovered the library flask_oauthlib.

### Things worth mentioning

- I derived this code from this here [GitHub example](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/example/github.py)
- There is also code there I omitted in order to keep the snippet short, that establishes that the server should use SSL (as per the request from the API that the redirect_uri should use HTTPS)
- The app manages to redirect me over at MeisterTask and asks for my permission. Once I grant it, it redirects to "https://127.0.0.1:5000/login/authorized?code=*some_token*" where I get the traceback. If I look with Chrome's debugging tools to the requests made and what I receive, I see that I get an 302 from the API, but I also get an access token.
- I run Windows 10 with Python 3.7.0

So what's the deal? What's the next step here? I've run out of things to try. Thank you for taking the time to solve this!

Comment: 302 (Found) is not an error. It is mostly use for redirects. There's a location header with the URL you should go to in the response.

Comment: I checked the header, there is no „Location” there